# How to install cordova crosswalk plugin manually in existing Android Project

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, crosswalk

I need to integrate crosswalk plugin in my Android project to support webview of older versions in android. I'm developing in Android Studio and tried to follow the instructions in this link: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html

My Android project is separated from the cordova base project so obviously
I got this message:

> "Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project."

My current app is working without the base cordova project
and I need to install the plugin manually.

Comment: You could run the method explained in the instructions in a sample hello-world like project, and then copy the plugin's js and java files to your project manually.

Comment: It's the first thing i tried to do, but the new project's hierarchy is totally different from my project, i don't know which files and directories i have to copy. also i wonder which code is responsible for loading the plugin instead of the standard android webview?

Comment: Please update the question with your project structure and the files used in index.html so I can know the paths.